# Kivy. Changing Layouts

Tags: python, kivy

I'm something of a newbie to Python and Kivy. After making some progress, I've hit a brick wall and no amount of internet searching can find an answer.

I have a python/kivy script which starts with a GridLayout selection menu. Then I would like to "Click Next" and replace the GridLayout with a BoxLayout to display the output. The Python script is:

```
import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from brp_stats import *
from dice_roller import *
#from display import *

race = ''
statblock = ''

class Test(GridLayout):

    def printcharacter(self,my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb):

        printable_stats = print_stats(my_sb)
        printable_rolls = print_rolls(my_cr)
        printable_scm = print_scm(my_scm)
        printable_scb = print_scb(my_scb)

        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(Label(text_size=(300, None),
                          text='Stats\n' + str(printable_stats)))
        self.add_widget(Label(text_size=(300, None),
                          text='Rolls\n' + str(printable_rolls)))
        self.add_widget(Label(text_size=(300, None),
                          text='SCM\n' + str(printable_scm)))
        self.add_widget(Label(text_size=(300, None),
                          text='SCB\n' + str(printable_scb)))

        wayout = Button(text='Way Out')
        self.add_widget(wayout)
        wayout.bind(on_press=self.canvas.clear)


#   def bar():
#       print ("BAR")

    def human(self,a,b):
        if b==True:
            self.Status="human"
            race=self.Status
            statblock = human()
            characteristic_rolls = rolls(statblock)
            skill_category_modifiers = scm(statblock)
            skill_category_bonuses = scb(statblock)
#           TestApp.foo()
#           Test.bar()
            Test.printcharacter( \ self,statblock,characteristic_rolls,skill_category_modifiers,skill_category_bonuses)

class TestApp(App):

#   def foo():
#       print ("FOO")

    def build(self):
        self.title="BRP Character Generator"
        return Test()


#### MAIN CODE ####

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

And the KV script is

```
<Test>:
    cols: 2
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: .2,.2,.2
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text: 'Human'
   CheckBox:
        group: 'race_group'
        on_active: root.human(*args)
    Button:
        text: 'Next'
        on_press: printcharacter()
```

What's happening is I select an option (Human in this example). It should wait until I click Next before displaying the results. However, as soon as I select Human, it immediately prints the result, in a GridLayout. Two questions spring to mind, which I'm hoping the experts here can help with:

1) Why does the Select screen not wait until I have clicked Next before displaying the results?
2) How do I swap the layout from Grid to Box when I display the second screen?

Any pointers or suggestions would be gratefully received.

Regards,
Colin

Answer (score 0):

Your Checkbox calls `Test.human(*args)` when it is active (pressed/selected), and the last line of `Test.human()` calls `Test.printcharacter()` which explains why it is printing before you hit the 'Next' button.

Since your `Test` class inherits from `GridLayout` the widgets you add to a root `Test` layout will be added as if to a GridLayout. There are several ways to handle switching the layout to a `BoxLayout`, one of which would be to not inherit directly from a particular Layout class and instead add/remove different Layout widgets to `Test` as needed.

For example, `Test` could start off with a `GridLayout` child widget that is the parent of the `Label`, `CheckBox`, and `Button` widgets. Then when you want to switch layouts for printing your results, you clear those widgets and start by adding a `BoxLayout` to `Test`.

Comment: Here's what I tried, after the usual imports (edited for brevity)
`class Display(Widget):
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

    def print_a_label(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        print_this = Label(text='Pressed Button 1')
        layout.add_widget(print_this)
    
class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        button1 = Button(text='Press This')
        layout.add_widget(button1)
        button1.bind(on_press=Display.print_a_label)
        return layout` It still doesn't display a BoxLayout